# xmlstarlet: remove tag with a specific attribute value and its children

Tags: xml, parsing, xmlstarlet

I have the following xml:

```
<systemList>
  <system>
    ...
  </system>
<system>
    <name>dreamcast</name>
    <fullname>Sega Dreamcast</fullname>
    <platform>dreamcast</platform>
    <theme>dreamcast</theme>
    <emulators>
      <emulator name="libretro">
        <cores>
          <core>stella</core>
        </cores>
      </emulator>
      <emulator name="retrorun">
        <cores>
          <core default="true">flycast</core>
        </cores>
      </emulator>
    </emulators>
  </system>

</systemList>
```

I want to remove this tab and all its sub tabs:

```
<emulator name="retrorun">
```

I tried to execute the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '/systemList/system[name='dreamcast']/emulators/emulator[@name='retrorun']' input.xml > output.xml
```

But it seems doing nothing, what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think it's just a typo - try changing `'dreamcast'` to `"dreamcast"`; you have a single quote inside a single quote.

Comment: you are right the problem was that one ;)